# CSS issue with table inside div / text ignoring right padding

Tags: html, css

I'm sure i'm doing a few things wrong here, but I can't seem to narrow down where the specific issue is that is causing the problem:

http://www.accessdigitalmedia.com/modaltest/ibtest.html

The text "1 Healthy Midday Meal for One Child Overseas" is ignoring the 5 px right padding on the parent div.  I think the problem *may* be the table inside the div. When I look at it with firebug, it appears that the table cells are shifted a pixel or two to the right and overflowing out of the parent container.

I am required to keep the tables in there for something the programmer I am working with needs. Can anyone help me get the content / text properly padded inside the box?

Thanks!

Comment: Now, this is some messed up HMTL.

Comment: What do you mean by "is ignoring the 5 px right padding on the parent div" ? There's 5px padding on the surrounding `td` element. But the text is definitely using it.

Answer (score 0):

If you give any padding to div, the content of that div -> table will be shifted.

For giving padding to the text either give it to anchor tag or heading tags which contains you text.

Answer (score 0):

```
h4 {
    width: 90%;
}

.table.cat-table-item {
    margin: 0 0 15px 5px;
}
```

Will do it.